# Everything seems to be rendered below wallpaper

Tags: fedora, kde, desktop-environments

I've got a fresh installation of Fedora 20 with KDE. Everything is out-of-box, no reconfiguring.
It starts normally, I get the standart logon screen. But when it starts the desktop, everything becomes strange: it looks like the wallpaper is being drawn on top. When I hover the mouse pointer on something, it shows, but then it dissapears. In console mode (another terminal) everything is right.
I understand my explanation is some messy, so I made a video of it: [video on youtube](http://youtu.be/P8yXV7IOtzY) (sorry for that format of screenshoting).
What I've tried:

- Total update. Didn't help;
- Googled every description of my problem I came up to. Couldn't find a single similar case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I think the problem was in nouveau driver for my Nvidia card. I installed proprietary driver from Nvidia and problem stopped occuring. It's mostly the Fedora problem, cause by default it uses only free drivers and only free repositories.

Answer (score 0):

I had this happen to me the first time I installed Xubuntu.  I looked for a solution for a while, and never found anything (that doesn't mean a solution doesn't exist).  I will say that since it was a fresh install, I just went ahead and reinstalled, and the problem did not persist.

Comment: Reinstall didn't help. It's strange.